# Parse Json response and check missing key in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I want to read the values from below sample Json response

```
"items": [
  {
    "kind": "books#volume",
    "id": "nwy8akU-nJUC",
    "volumeInfo": {
      "title": "Light In August",
      "authors": ["William Faulkner"],
      "publisher": "Random House",
      "publishedDate": "2013-07-05",
      "pageCount": 384,
      "categories": ["Fiction"]
    },
    "saleInfo": {
      "country": "IN",
      "saleability": "FOR_SALE",
      "isEbook": true,
      "listPrice": {
        "amount": 339.0,
        "currencyCode": "INR"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

When I read the response and iterate in a loop as an array, amount & currencyCode keys are missing in the second result thus its totally ignored in the array. Please help me as to how to loop through the key and identify if the key is not there then set value null.

I have written a below sample code

```
testRunner.runTestStepByName("Volumes1")
def responseContent = context.testCase.getTestStepByName("Volumes1").getProperty("response").value
JsonSlurper jsonResponseContent = new JsonSlurper()
def jsonResponseObject = jsonResponseContent.parseText(responseText)
titleCount = jsonResponseObject.items.volumeInfo.title.size
arrayTitle = jsonResponseObject.items.volumeInfo.title
arrayAuthor = jsonResponseObject.items.volumeInfo.authors
arrayPublisher = jsonResponseObject.items.volumeInfo.publisher
arrayPublishDate = jsonResponseObject.items.volumeInfo.publishedDate
arrayPageCount = jsonResponseObject.items.volumeInfo.pageCount
arrayCategories = jsonResponseObject.items.volumeInfo.categories
arrayAmount = jsonResponseObject.items.saleInfo.listPrice.amount
arrayCurrencyCode = jsonResponseObject.items.saleInfo.listPrice.currencyCode
```

Comment: Please post the valid json response or edit and add the raw response.

Comment: @Rao I am unable paste the response as its too lengthy hence Here is Json request url [link] (https://www.googleapis.com//books/v1/volumes?q=The Stand)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is it ok to read just exist values for amount and currencyCode from the response? or do you need to set those keys in the reseponse with null? what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: By the way, there are `listprice` and `retailPrice` under `salesinfo`. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: Thanks for the response... I would like to read all elements in volume info and saleinfo(listprice) alone. Also amount and country code should be null if listprice is missing in the response

Comment: Are you needing these values for assertion? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
arrayAmount = jsonResponseObject.items.saleInfo?.listPrice?.amount
arrayCurrencyCode = jsonResponseObject.items.saleInfo?.listPrice?.currencyCode 

println "list price amount : ${arrayAmount}"
println "list price currency code : ${arrayCurrencyCode}"
```

The above uses null safe. Refer [here](http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2013/08/20/groovys-null-safe-operator) for more details.